# How can I submit XML in an HTML form POST parameter, using Form Builder

Tags: orbeon

I'd like to send XML to a service. The description of that service states that "The XML Document should be posted uriencoded, with a UTF-8 character set as paramaeter 'xml' to ~/api/xmlapi.php" and there is an example script:

```
xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject(receiveXML);
var url = "api/xmlapi.php";
var params = "xml=" + document.getElementById('xml').value;
xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xmlHttp.send(params);
```

The format of the XML is also specified by the service, and the XML needs to be "filled" with values entered by users in form fields.

I'm trying to use Form Builder to create an HTTP service, and have tried all the standard options with no success (valid http - 200. but no response). Maybe something to do with the "xml=" parameter setting.

Do I need to customise the source code of the submission?

Comment: Based on the PHP snippet you quoted, that service expects the data to be be sent in a HTML form POST, as the value of the `xml` parameter. Instead, by default, XForms will send it as the body of the POST. Now, when would you like the data to be submitted? And what part of the data? Is it just a few fields, or the whole form? What is the format of the XML you want to send?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was hoping to send it on a button press (as an Action on a Service) passing api defined xml with xpath substitutions. Do I need to add the "xml=" into the submission definition by editing the source?

Comment: I am just wondering about the XML format of what you need to send to the service. Would you like to: (a) send all the fields in the current form, in whatever XML format is used by Orbeon Forms, or (b) do you have a specific XML document in which the values need to go, in which case maybe only a subset of the values need to be sent.

Comment: (b) I need to send a specific xml document with a subset of the form data values.

Comment: OK, got it, thank you for the details, and I posted an answer below. It this will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I have to say that Form Builder wasn't designed with this use case in mind, so bear with me if what I describe here, at times, feels convoluted. If you want to just run this example instead of having to recreate it (which I recommend), download the [source of the final form](https://gist.github.com/avernet/5105343) first, paste it in a new form from the Edit Source dialog, replacing the source of that form.

1. First create a service. In the PHP code above, the parameter used to pass the XML is named `xml`, so the request body needs to be `<xml/>`. (If it was `gaga`, the request body would need to be `<gaga/>`.)

   [image: service]
2. Create an action, here triggered when a button is pressed. It takes the value of a control `xml-sent` to populate the value of the `xml` parameter, hence the `/xml` *Destination XPath Expression*. What is this `xml-sent`? We'll see this in the next step.

   [image: action]
3. In an "internal" section, which you set to always be hidden, add a text output control, name it `xml-sent`, and set it to be calculated as in the expression below. I put this expression on 3 lines, to be easier to read here, but you need to enter it one line in Form Builder's *Validation Property* dialog. Note how you are creating here the XML document you want to send, whatever it is, and then using `saxon:serialize()` to convert that XML document into "text", which becomes the value of the `xml-sent` control. For debugging, you can make the section visible, so the XML is shown in the form, allowing you to see what will be sent to the service.

   ```
   saxon:serialize(xxf:element('person', (
       xxf:element('first', string($first-name)), 
       xxf:element('first', string($last-name)))), 'xml')
   ```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I haven't got access to the server until the weekend and will try then. Not convoluted, makes perfect sense.